# How to rename data within a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe but the numbering of the months is all jumbled. I need to change the following rows to the following, but i'm struggling to see an easy way through. I'm aware that this code changes the data, but it's just a case of working out the puzzle without adding columns together.

```
data$column[data$column == "0"] <- "7"
```

- 0 <- 7
- 1 <- 8
- 2 <- 9
- 3 <- 10
- 4 <- 1
- 5 <- 2
- 6 <- 3
- 7 <- 4
- 8 <- 5
- 9 <- 6

Thank you

Comment: It seems that you could use simple indexing like `c(7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)[as.numeric(data$column) + 1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe `plyr::mapvalues()` can help you here:

```
library(plyr)
df$column <- mapvalues(df$column, from = c(0,1:9), to = c(7:10, 1:6))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
data$column <- (data$column + 7) %% 10
```